# Clover : Statement and Method codecoverage

Tags: methods, code-coverage, clover

In the nice html code coverage that clover generates , I did not see any specific code coverage for method and statement. I just have one number that is overall code coverage. I believe we would like to get the individual percentage for method and statement. I was actually surprised to find not to find one on the code coverage report. 
Do people use method or statement code coverage , if so how can I get it through clover html coverage report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Marek [Atlassian]

it's possible to have extra coverage metrics in the HTML report. You have to use clover-report task and declare the current , columns element in it, as shown below.

```
<clover-report>
<current outfile="report/html">
  <format type="html"/>
  <columns>
     <coveredMethods format="%"/>
     <coveredStatements format="%"/>
     <coveredBranches format="%"/>
     <coveredElements format="bar"/>
   </columns>
 </current>
</clover-report>
```